# Join for List<Array> in lambda expression chain syntax

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, lambda

I am an amateur at Joins, but I am trying to use expression chain syntax instead of a LINQ statment. Most examples I find have used arrays or list of classes { List`<class`> }; but nothing for a list of arrays { List`<array`> }

```
List<int[]> needHelp = new List<int[]>{ 
new int[3] { 10, 20, 50},
new int[3] { 10, 21, 53},
new int[3] { 10, 22, 55},
new int[3] { 11, 20, 60},
new int[3] { 11, 22, 51} };

List<int[]> ghosts = new List<int[]>{ 
new int[3] { 10, 45, 65},
new int[3] { 11, 34, 60} };
```

The LINQ "query" syntax that works is:

```
List<int[]> result = (from h in needHelp join g in ghosts on h[0] equals g[0] 
                      where h[1] == 21 select g).ToList();
```

But this "Method" expression chain syntax isn't working for me:

```
List<int[]> result = needHelp.Join(ghosts, x=>x[0], y=>y[0], (x,y) => y ).Where(x => x[1] == 21).ToList();
```

For those interested I have found that this lambda expression chain can print out a List of arrays without having to use two foreach loops.

```
result.ForEach( x => { Array.ForEach(x, e => Console.Write(e + " ") ); Console.WriteLine();} );
```

Ok well I think I found my own solution, and it was by changing the location of the where clause. But what is the reason the Where has to come before the join and not work after? I read on a post that if this was a database call the where class being before ".Join" then it is processed on the server and not the client. I assume then that trying to use it after the Join it is out-of-scope of the data that is left, which in this instance would be y (List`<int[]`> ghosts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join`s and `Where`s are not interchangeable in general.

If you read your expression chain "out loud", it would read something like this: **first get me all arrays in `ghosts` that match up a first element with something in `needHelp`, and then select from that those arrays which have the second element equal to 21**.

So at the point after the `Join`, you are only left with arrays that come from the `ghosts` List. Your WHERE clause then returns nothing, since nothing in `ghosts` has second element equal to 21. You are checking for that in the `needHelp` List.

I would recommend that you do swap the `Join` and the `Where`:

```
List<int[]> result = needHelp.Where(x => x[1] == 21).Join(ghosts, x=>x[0], y=>y[0], (x,y) => y ).ToList();
```

In case it was a source of confusion for you, don't think that the `x` and `y` variables in the functions mean anything over multiple functions. Your `Where` call related `x` to `needHelp`, but that doesn't mean that the `x` in the `Join` function relates to `needHelp`; it references the output of the `Where`, which are elements from `ghosts`.

Comment: Yes that is what I come to understand that the return off the Join is only y (ghosts) and therefore the where coming after would have no results.
Also I do understand as well the x in the where lambda is completely seperate from the x in the Join which is a KeyPointer at needHelp.

Comment: This answer helped me then, and this has had over a hundred views so maybe it has helped others; hopefully if so anyone in the future it helps will upvote your answer. I would like to request that you would upvote the question if you felt it was a good question, and thoroughly explained. Thanks

Comment: I went ahead, even this was for some online coding puzzle i did what feels like ages ago. I had been trying to clean up my questions, as OS is refusing to let me ask any questions now. I currently have it cleaned up to 3 questions with a total of 4 upvotes and 4 questions with 0 upvotes and 1 with a -1 vote. It was telling me I was banned from asking any new questions, now It still is telling me I have reached my question limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your Join method isn't the translation of the query syntax you gave.

Your query filter on `h[1]` (`x[1]` in the Join) but you select only `y` (`g` in your query) so the Where after that applies on the wrong thing.

Here is the direct translation of your query :

```
List<int[]> result = 
    needHelp
    .Join (ghosts, x => x[0], y => y[0], (x, y) => new { x, y })
    .Where (anon => anon.x[1] == 21)
    .Select (anon => anon.y)
    .ToList ();
```

Comment: You claim my syntax from the LINQ query expression to the lambda chain expression is not correct? You are pointing out what I believe is called anonymous input parameters and there for the h in the query is also an alias.
As to your Join lambda line, that is like mine, except it returns both List<array> which is fine if i was looking for both, but in this instance I only needed the ghosts List.

Comment: @Edward you need both after the join ; in your query it's the same you use h in the where clause and g in the select clause. It means both were selected from the join (what Ivan called transparent identifier in his answer). If you have looked more carefully in my "chain" I have the same logical step as in your query : Joining, then filtering and finally projecting ; and his this projection I only keep the items coming from ghosts. If it weren't the case and I was returning something more it wouldn't compile as the return type wouldn't be right

Answer (score 0):

The exact method syntax equivalent of this query syntax

```
from h in needHelp join g in ghosts on h[0] equals g[0] 
where h[1] == 21
select g
```

is something like this:

```
needHelp.Join(ghosts, h => h[0], g => g[0], (h, g) => new { h, g })
    .Where(x => x.h[1] == 21)
    .Select(x => x.g);
```

The query syntax uses so called "transparent indentifiers" which hide those intermediate anonymous types, and that's why is preferable for queries involving joins.

Speaking about joins and where in general, IMO it's always better to apply the filters before joining, especially in LINQ to Objects, because database query optimizers will rearrange the filters and join operations anyway. So a better query (from both performance and memory allocations) would be:

```
needHelp.Where(h => h[1] == 21).Join(ghosts, h => h[0], g => g[0], (h, g) => g);
```

Comment: This makes since that the where in this statement works because you return both Lists, where I only returned the one.
So if your opinion was to put the where first, then why not incorporate that in the answer you gave?

Comment: Done. I didn't initially because I was thinking that you want to just get the equivalent method syntax for your query. As a general advice, try to use the same variable names in order to easily associate the parts of one syntax to another. Which is not always possible, but at least should be close. With more than one join (and if you need also left outer joins), the method syntax is really a pain.